# How to run a function everyday at a certain time then stop after a specific hour?

Tags: python

I have a script that will scrape Facebook post in a while loop. But to prevent getting banned by Facebook I prefer the scraping function `run(self)` only run at a certain time and stop after 1 hour. How can I achieve that? I saw someone post about starting a function at a certain time but not stopping it after a specific hour.

Code to start a function at a certain time:

```
import schedule
import time

def job(t):
    print ("I'm working...", t)
    return

schedule.every().day.at("18:44").do(job,'It is 01:00')

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(60) # wait one minute
```

My script code

```
    def run(self):

        while True:
            try:
                wanted = "Pecahan setiap negeri (Kumulatif):"  # wanted post
                for post in get_posts("myhealthkkm", pages=5):
                    if post.get("post_text") is not None and wanted in post.get("post_text"):
                        # print("Found", t)
                        listposts.append(post.get("post_text"))
                        # append until 3 page finish then go here

                time.sleep(1)
                print(listposts)
                global listView
                if listposts != 0:
                    listView = listposts.copy()
                    print(listView)
                listposts.clear()
            except exceptions.TemporarilyBanned:
                print("Temporarily banned, sleeping for 10m")
                time.sleep(600)
```

I want the `run()` function only execute at 3pm and stop after 1 hour which is 4pm everyday. How can I achieve this goal ? Thanks

Comment: Just put a time check inside your `run` function? Record the start time time at the beginning of the function, then inside the `while` loop check to see if 1 hour has elapsed, and if so, exit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the respond from @larsks, I tried to put a time check inside the function and exit the loop if it reached `3600second` which is equal to 1 hour.

Here is the sample code:

```
import schedule
import time


def job():
    program_starts = time.time()

    while True:
        now = time.time()
        timeframe = now - program_starts
        print("It has been {0} seconds since the loop started".format(timeframe))
        if timeframe > 3600:
            break

schedule.every().day.at("19:20:30").do(job)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    #time.sleep(60) # wait one minute
```