# Nothing happened when scheduling a function to start at a certain time

Tags: python

I have a class to start a thread for a while loop. I tried to scheduling the thread class to start within a certain time but it doesn't work:

```
def test():
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()

schedule.every().day.at("17:25:50").do(test)
```

The function does not do anything even the time reached "17:25:50"

My full code:

```
import discord
import random
import time
import asyncio

import schedule
from facebook_scraper import get_posts, _scraper, exceptions
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
import threading
import time
import re
class LEDManager(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, id_manager):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.id_manager = int(id_manager)

    def run(self):
        while True:
            try:
                wanted = "Pecahan setiap negeri (Kumulatif):"  # wanted post
                for post in get_posts("myhealthkkm", pages=5):
                    if post.get("post_text") is not None and wanted in post.get("post_text"):
                        # print("Found", t)
                        listposts.append(post.get("post_text"))
                        # append until 3 page finish then go here

                time.sleep(1)
                print(listposts)
                global listView
                if listposts != 0:
                    listView = listposts.copy()
                    print(listView)
                listposts.clear()
            except exceptions.TemporarilyBanned:
                print("Temporarily banned, sleeping for 10m")
                time.sleep(600)


def main():
    thread_id = ("0")
    led_index = 0
    thread_list = list()
    for objs in thread_id:
        thread = LEDManager(led_index)
        thread_list.append(thread)
        led_index += 1
    for thread in thread_list:
        thread.start()
        time.sleep(1)

def test():
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()

schedule.every().day.at("17:25:50").do(test)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add these lines:

```
while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

You should add them at the end of the file, so the system will keep checking forever, if "the job" needs to be done (if the hour is "17:25:50").

And here is the full documentation to see how to use the schedule module:
https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Comment: I tried to put the while true statement at the last line of my code [Code](https://ibb.co/bXhGLLn), but still it cannot be execute at the specific time

Comment: Can you try to put the `client.run(token)` you added at the end at the start of the `main` or `test` function, instead of where it is now?

Comment: I cannot put `client.run(token)` inside the test function because it suppose to run the discord bot. The reason why I need to put the schedule in the class is because I only need it to scrape when a certain time. If i put `client.run(token)` inside the `test` or `main`, my discord bot couldn't be run. Here is my previous question if you are interested: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68725410/how-to-run-a-function-everyday-at-a-certain-time-then-stop-after-a-specific-hour?noredirect=1#comment121456994_68725410)

Comment: I tried to put `client.run(token)` inside the test, surprisingly it worked. But my loop doesn't work either. It only able to run the bot instead of my class

Comment: Now i see the problem, if i put `test` above the `client.run(token)` it will worked. But if its below the `client.run(token)` it will not worked. So that's mean if I executed the `client.run(token)` first, it will not work even the schedule has reach the time

Comment: I solved it. Its not the schedule fault because my `client.run(token)` is blocking the rest of the code.

Comment: Oh ok prefect :)